How to load and render an OBJ file in Three.js?
I'm trying to render an object file with three.js.
When I put the file into "3dviewer.net" and check it, it renders fine, but when I run the code locally, I just get a black screen.
How do I fix it?
Im current use NextJs, three.js
The code is shown below.
thankyou for check my question
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import * as THREE from "three";
import { OrbitControls } from "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls";
import { OBJLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader";

export const Viewer3D: React.FC = () => {
  const mountRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!mountRef.current) return;

    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75,window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,0.1,1000);
    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    mountRef.current.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
    scene.add(ambientLight);

    const pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1);
    pointLight.position.set(5, 5, 5);
    scene.add(pointLight);

    camera.position.z = 5;

    const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

    const loader = new OBJLoader();
    const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial();
    const texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(
      "../../../lib/models/texturedMesh.obj"
    );
    material.map = texture;

    loader.load("../../../lib/models/texturedMesh.obj", (object) => {
      object.traverse((child) => {
        if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
          child.material = material;
        }
      });
      scene.add(object);
    });

    const animate = () => {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      controls.update();
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
    };
    animate();

    const handleResize = () => {
      const width = window.innerWidth;
      const height = window.innerHeight;

      camera.aspect = width / height;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

      renderer.setSize(width, height);
    };
    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);

    // Cleanup
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
      mountRef.current?.removeChild(renderer.domElement);
    };
  }, []);

  return <div ref={mountRef} style={{ width: "300px", height: "300px" }} />;
};


and my obj file look like
# 
# Wavefront OBJ file
# Created with AliceVision
# 
mtllib texturedMesh.mtl

g TexturedMesh
v 0.867149 0.656084 3.034780
v 0.840995 0.658468 3.043190
v 0.847674 0.652272 3.023960
v 0.871786 0.649374 3.016930
v 0.824603 0.654330 3.034690
...

i expected rendering 3d
